# Lighttpd reverse proxy HTTPS to another server on HTTP

Tags: reverse-proxy, https, mod-proxy, lighttpd

I've a Lighttpd server running on HTTPS, and I want to have one subdirectory on the server act as a reverse proxy for a separate server that runs on HTTP. I've tried following guides on doing both proxy and url rewrite, but something to do with how the SSL is set up is interfering.

```
$SERVER["socket"] == ":81" {
    url.rewrite-once = ( "^/directory/(.*)$" => "/index.html" )
    proxy.server  = ( "" => ( "" => ( "host" => "192.0.0.1", "port" => 123 )))
}

$HTTP["scheme"] == "http" {
     $HTTP["host"] =~ ".*" {
        url.redirect = (".*" => "https://%0$0")
     }
}

$SERVER["socket"] == ":443" {
        ssl.engine = "enable"
        ssl.ca-file = "/etc/lighttpd/fullchain.pem"
        ssl.pemfile = "/etc/lighttpd/server.pem"
        $HTTP["url"] =~ "^/directory/" {
               proxy.server = ( "" => ( "" => ( "host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 81)))
        }
}
```

My intention was that going to /directory/ would redirect you to the 192.0.0.1:123/index.html. I followed [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859956/lighttpd-as-reverse-proxy) which mentioned doing the first redirect to port 81, then redirecting port 81 to the second server.

This doesn't seem to work and just gets stuck in a redirection loop, and always returns a 301 to the https site.

If I don't do the :81 redirect, I can get the bottom proxy.server to redirect to the right place, but it keeps the /directory/ ending which doesn't get to where I need it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

lighttpd 1.4.46 and later have a feature in mod_proxy which allows remapping url-path prefixes.  See the 'proxy.header' directive and "map-urlpath" sub-option.

https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModProxy

This feature avoids the double-proxy config you are trying to use.

lighttpd 1.4.46 was released just over a year ago and the latest lighttpd release is lighttpd 1.4.51.